# How can i clear edit text value when popbackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i have an `edittext` in fragment A which is for static search in category list. When i replace fragment A with Fragment B and clicked to back button `edittext` is still showing what i wrote before replaced fragment. Here is what i was tried FragmentA's `oncreateview` and `onactivitycreated`. But thats not working(i want to set `edit text` value to empty string when `popbackstack` is called) :

```
 if (customTextWatcher == null)
    {
        customTextWatcher = new CustomTextWatcher();
        searchET.addTextChangedListener(customTextWatcher);
    }
    else {
        searchET.removeTextChangedListener(customTextWatcher);
        searchET.setText("");
        searchET.addTextChangedListener(customTextWatcher);
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may clear the EditText when you show the second fragment. Elsewhere you may intercept the `onBackPressed` into the fragment (the method `onBackPressed` is actually called into the activity, you should pass that information to the fragment currently shown).

I think the first one is a cleaner solution.

Comment: can i clear edit text in onDestroyView? @Massimo Actually i don't want to send fragmentA reference to FragmentB.

Comment: It makes little sense to clear it in onDestroyView, maybe you can clear it in onDetach. But you should use those methods for other things, it should be better if the components which fire the fragments' replacement said fragment A to clear the EditText

Comment: i can go a lot of fragment from fragmentA. So i think there should be other way to do this. Why can't i set edittext value empty string in oncreateView?

Comment: you can, but actually onCreateView is not called a second time, because the fragment's view has already been created. You may try to clear the EditText in onAttach (the EditText will be cleared when the fragment will be re-attached to the activity)

Comment: i am starting fragmenttranscation with "replace" not "add". So oncreateview is definitely being called.

onattach is not working too.

Comment: Another solution may be addOnBackStackChangedListener on your support FragmentManager. From there you may know when fragment A is your "on top" fragment, then you can clear your EditText (again, I think this is not the best solution, the best one would be the first one I wrote, but you know how your code is structured)

Answer (score 6):

For clearing the UI widgets of fragment on which user come back after pop/backpress

```
  @Override
        public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
            if (searchEdittext != null)     // for resetting this edittext
                searchEdittext.setText(BLANK_STRING);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What triggers the switch of Fragments from A to B? That's where I'd put the logic for clearing that EditText. For example, if a user presses a button that triggers the switch of fragments, clear the EditText in the View.OnClickListener's onClick(View view) method.

```
EditText et = (EditText) root.findViewById(...);
Button b1 = (Button) root.findViewById(....);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        et.setText("");
        // logic for switching fragment A to B
    }
}
```